# Azure ARM, Stream Analytics and Function App

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is there a way of make Stream Analytics wait until the sourcecontrol of the function app is finished?

I'm trying to add an function app output for my Stream Analytics jobs, but it fails:

| Resource | Type | Status |

| function-app-xyvfjtuivnvow/aggregate | Microsoft.Web/sites/functions | NotFound |

My function 'aggregate' is deployed by the sourcecontrols resource dependency inside the function app.

If I deploy the app service plan and the function app in one template, and the stream analytics in another one after that, it works correctly, but it fails in the same template.

Params and variable has been deleted for readability purposes, and the template is being deployed via Azure Portal.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0",
  "resources": [{
    "name": "[variables('streamAnalyticsName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs",
    "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols', variables('functionAppName'), 'web')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard"
      },
      "inputs": [],
      "outputs": [{
        "name": "aggregate",
        "type": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/outputs",
        "properties": {
          "datasource": {
            "type": "Microsoft.AzureFunction",
            "properties": {
              "functionAppName": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
              "functionName": "aggregate",
              "apiKey": "[listSecrets(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/functions', variables('functionAppName'), 'aggregate'), '2016-08-01').key]"
            }
          }
        }
      }],
      "functions": [],
      "transformation": {
        "name": "query",
        "properties": {
          "streamingUnits": 1,
          "query": "..."
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "name": "[variables('servicePlanName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
    "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
    "kind": "app",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
      "name": "[variables('servicePlanName')]",
      "workerTierName": null,
      "adminSiteName": null,
      "hostingEnvironmentProfile": null,
      "perSiteScaling": false,
      "reserved": false,
      "targetWorkerCount": 0,
      "targetWorkerSizeId": 0
    },
    "sku": {
      "name": "S1",
      "tier": "Standard",
      "size": "S1",
      "family": "S",
      "capacity": 1
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "kind": "functionapp",
    "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
    "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
      "enabled": true,
      "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('servicePlanName'))]",
      "defaultDocuments": [],
      "siteConfig": {
        "alwaysOn": true,
        "nodeVersion": "8.9.4",
        "phpVersion": "",
        "pythonVersion": "",
        "javaVersion": "",
        "javaContainer": "",
        "javaContainerVersion": "",
        "appSettings": [...]
      }
    },
    "dependsOn": [
      "[variables('servicePlanName')]"
    ],
    "resources": [{
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
      "name": "web",
      "type": "sourcecontrols",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('functionAppName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "repoUrl": "...",
        "branch": "master",
        "isManualIntegration": true
      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: I think if you deploy the code of your function app as artifacts in the ARM template it should work, otherwise you may have to split your ARM template

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I have tried to deploy my function's code as artifacts but docs are so poor and I can't make them works. I have my code on a VSTS repository, could you provide some examples?

Comment: The principle is to upload your binaries to blob storage and reference it in the ARM template. You may split your ARM template in two and deploy your app in 3 steps ???

Comment: https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/03/deploy-azure-web-app-using-arm-template-from-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: As I said before, I could split my template in two, firstly I could deploy all the apps with source controls and after that I could deploy the second template with the stream analytics which has the function app dependency.

Anyways, I'm reading the blog you posted before and will try to deploy all my resources in 1 step.